# Issue with JTextArea in Swing

Tags: java, swing, textarea, nullpointerexception

I am having trouble updating a text area.

I declare `textArea` in `gui.java`:

```
JTextArea textArea;
```

I start up the GUI..

```
public void startGUI() {
        // These are all essential GUI pieces
        JLabel jLabInstruction, jLaberror;
        JLabel copyright = new JLabel("");
        JTextField uI = new JTextField("");
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea("");
        JButton jbtnSubmit;

        final JFrame jfrm = new JFrame("app name!");
        jfrm.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        jfrm.setSize(300, 300);
        jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        textArea = new JTextArea(5, 20);
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        jLabInstruction = new JLabel("SYSTEM: Please type in a command: ");
        jbtnSubmit = new JButton("Submit");
        jLaberror = new JLabel("");
        textArea.setMargin(new Insets(10,10,10,10));

        jfrm.add(jLaberror);
        jfrm.add(textArea);
        jfrm.add(jLabInstruction);
        jfrm.add(uI);
        jfrm.add(jbtnSubmit);
        jfrm.add(new JSeparator(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL));
        jfrm.add(copyright);
        jfrm.setVisible(true);
    }
```

And I have a method that writes to the `textArea` above:

```
public void writeToTextArea(String userInputText) {
        textArea.append("\nSYSTEM: "
                + userInputText);
    }
```

Also, in `tasks.java`, I am able to call on this last method:

```
gui.writeToTextArea("PROGRAM STARTED!");
```

My problem is that the text area field is not updating. nothing is being inputted.  I am thinking it is because it can't find what `textArea` is.  I am getting an:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are declaring another variable called `textArea` in your `startGUI` function, which is hiding the class level `textArea`. Which is why you get an NPE when you try to write to the text area later on in your program.

```
JTextArea textArea;

public void startGUI() {
    JLabel jLabInstruction, jLaberror;
    JLabel copyright = new JLabel("");
    JTextField uI = new JTextField("");
    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(""); //<-- Your hiding your class variable here

    // ... rest of your code
}
```

Comment: i tried commenting this line out, and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Don't comment the line out. Just stop redeclaring the variable. Aka `textArea = new JTextArea("");`.

Comment: +1. @droidus, you can't comment out the line because you need to create the text area.

Comment: i am getting more errors:    userInput.askGetInput("There were errors creating the file.  Would you like to continue ahead with diagnostics? (Type \"y\" or \"yes\", or \"n\" or \"no\".) This will only take a minute."); (taskBckg.java), as well as here too... // Writes to the text area
 public void writeToTextArea(String userInputText) {
  textArea.append("\nSYSTEM: " + userInputText);
 }

 // Ask the user for input
 public void askGetInput(String outText) {
  writeToTextArea(outText);
 }

Comment: i still get the "java.lang.NullPointerException" error, and am not sure why.  it only happens after adding these 3 statements...

Comment: @droidus - you should ask separate questions for the other issues that came up. And do feel free to mark my answer correct if it helped you fix the particular error mentioned originally. Don't forget to include your code samples in the new questions.